# python write() function automatically creates newline in file

Tags: python, numpy, newline

I am using the write() to print arrays to a file which will be read by another script, like this:

```
file2write=open("arrays.txt",'w')
file2write.write(str(array1)+'\n')
file2write.write(str(array2))
file2write.close()
```

I want each array occupying only one line to be read by the other script, however i am getting this when the array grows larger:

```
1 [ 0.   0.   0.  -0.4  0.6  0.   0.   0.   0.  -0.4  0.6 -0.4  0.6  0.2
2   0. ]
3 [0.1 0.3 0.3 0.1 0.1 0.5 0.5 0.7 0.7 0.3 0.3 0.5 0.5 0.7 0.7]
```

How to get this, despite the size of the array:

```
1 [ 0.   0.   0.  -0.4  0.6  0.   0.   0.   0.  -0.4  0.6 -0.4  0.6  0.2   0. ]
2 [0.1 0.3 0.3 0.1 0.1 0.5 0.5 0.7 0.7 0.3 0.3 0.5 0.5 0.7 0.7]
```

Comment: Are you sure there's an actual newline being put into the file? Many text editors will wrap long lines so it *looks* like it may span multiple lines but it actually only occupies one. Can you try to find the line wrapping feature in the editor you're using to view your file and turn it off, then re-check your output?

Comment: Python `write()` doesn't write anything other than what you give it. It won't add newlines by itself.

Comment: No, it is spliting the line after a certain size. I get this error when i read from the script. SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing ....
    xblocos = literal_eval(x) ....  in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    [0.,0.,0.,-0.4,0.6,0.,0.,0.,0.,-0.4,0.6,-0.4,0.6,0.2
                                                                            ^

Comment: It is a numpy array and I read it from the file like this: coords = open("coordenadas_blocos.txt", "r")
coords = coords.readlines()
x = coords[0]
y = coords[1]
x = re.sub("\n", "", x)
x = re.sub("\s+", ",", x)
x = x.replace("[,","[")
xblocos = literal_eval(x)       ... same thing for y

Answer (score 0):

The`str(array1)` is splitting the numpy array into multiple lines.

One way to avoid this is to use `str(list(array1))`

Another way is to use `numpy.array2string(array1, max_line_width=1000)`, or whatever is a reasonable line width.

Comment: Yeah, I have just find out it by myself right now! Seems that numpy defaults to print arrays with a fixed width of 70 characters. To use list(array) solved the problem. Thanks =)